# not found: type SparkContext || object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write one simple program in Scala but when I use **SparkContext** in Intellij this is throwing an error. Can someone give me any solution?

```
Scala 3.1.1

Spark version 3.2.1
```

[image: Please see the below picture]

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Wordcount extends App {
  val sc = new SparkContext("Local[*]","wordcount")

}
```

Comment: I guess spark is not yet support scala 3

Comment: But I read on the Internet that Spark 3 is compatible with Scala 3. 

https://www.47deg.com/blog/using-scala-3-with-spark/#using-scala-3-with-spark-0

Comment: How did you add **Spark** to your project? does it work if you use your build tool instead of your IDE? - BTW, don't use `App`; especially with **Spark**, just write a normal main method - About **Scala 3**, while you can use **Spark** with it thought dark magic, no cloud vendor supports that and the trick to use it from **Scala 3** is not 100% bullet proof, just use `2.12` which is supported in the market or `2.11` which is the most common one.

Comment: I figured out the issue, Spark is compatible with Java 8 - 11, I had to degrade my Java version 17 to Java 11. Now it is working fine for me.